# (simple?) error with findpeaks and if loop

Tags: matlab, maxima

I'm trying to find the local maxima of a data set using the `findpeaks()` function and so far I have this code:

```
[pks, locs] = findpeaks(signal);
max_times = zeros(size(locs));

if n = 1:size(locs);
max_times(n) = (times(locs(n)));
end
```

***What am I trying to do?*** Well I have a set of signal data and the corresponding times. I want to get the local maxima values and output two vectors; the maxima signal values and the times that they occured.

***How am I doing it?*** I'm using the findpeaks function to find the peaks (pks) and location (locs) of the maxima. I'm then setting up a blank array the same length as the locs vector and then using an if loop to fill up the empty max_times(n) vector with the times that the maxima occur

***The problem?*** I keep getting this error`Expression or statement is incomplete or incorrect.` about my if loop. I don't understand what this means/ how do I solve this problem/ edit my code to get it to do what I want?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are thinking is totally wrong.

`If` is not a loop its a conditional statement

what you want here is a `for` loop

```
for n = 1:size(locs)
    % your code
end
```

also `times` take two parameter and you should figure it out yourself what it should be